# Class AB Amplifier With Single Supply

Tags: transistors, amplifier, speakers, guitar-amplifier, class-ab

I'm designing an amplifier which is to be run off of a single 20 V supply (in the circuit, V+ = 20 V, V- = GND).  Q2 and Q3 are used to bias Q4 and Q1. Since the circuit is running off a single 20 V supply, a capacitor is required before the speaker.

The circuit works in LT spice, though I am having trouble implementing the output capacitor.  I know the capacitor will form a filter with the speaker, in this case having a cut-off frequency of around 40 Hz.  When I put the capacitor in the real circuit however, the signal is almost completely attenuated- the only reason I can think of is that there is some funky stuff going on with the speaker that I didn't simulate (inductance etc).  I didn't think this would make a huge difference however, as I've also tried with a large 4700 uF capacitor.

[image]

Comment: Do you then have \$\pm10\:\text{V}\$? You don't say and we don't have all of the schematic, either? Where does the other end of the load go, for example? And I haven't tried to suss out that schematic. Would you mind talking about your considerations when designing it?

Comment: Doesn't look like class AB to me, more like class B.

Comment: Humm ... R16 and R17 seems very high (1 Meg ?) Double feedback on the opamp ?

Comment: Don't post schematics then amend that schematic in your words. It is bad practice and leads to confusion. Schematics trump words no matter what you say.

Comment: Where is the input coming from? Is there any coupling cap? If there's none then the output may hit one of the rails. It may also be necessary to place a relatively high capacitor across R47.

Comment: Please post a clean and complete schematic. It looks like there is some stuff missing and there's also some stuff in the upper right corner we have no idea what it's for. You also seem to be using both ground symbols and V-, are these the same net or is the simulation using a split rail power supply?

Comment: C1 is shown as unpolarised but in reality it will be electrolytic; please make sure it is correctly connected (one end will be about 10V, the other at GND).

Comment: This seems overcomplicated and honestly I don't know what's going on here. Why don't you use a simple op amp to amplifie voltage and class AB output (two bjts, two diodes, current source) Also that double feedback seems weird to me, why not have only one, the one with R44 connected to output capacitor.

Comment: It'd be great if you had an oscilloscope, but you should at least have a multimeter. Measure all the DC operating points and compare them to the simulated circuit, maybe you'll find some significant deviation somewhere.

Comment: What is the reason for C11 (10 uF) and C25 ( 47 nF) in series ?

Answer (score 2):

Your transistor Q5 has a voltage gain of 100 times at radio frequencies but a gain of 8 times at audio frequencies because the emitter resistor value is much too low and the emitter capacitor value is much too low.

In your power amplifier R16, R17 and C2 are not needed but an input coupling capacitor feeding signals is needed.

I cropped the power amplifier and turned around upside-down transistors. You use 15A driver transistors to produce only 50mA!
The output stage is very odd having emitter-followers in series and the driver transistors are turning OFF the output transistors. When your output transistors need lots of base current the 200 ohm base resistors provide very low base currents.

[image: preamp]

[image: 2W amplifier]

Comment: The hFE for those power transistors is like 20 or less, so the output impedance is effectively 10 ohms with the 200 ohm base resistors **?**

Comment: Nobody makes an audio amplifier like yours. Use the Sziklai pairs that I show, with low value emitter resistors and with base biasing. The output impedance is extremely low due to the very high open loop gain of the opamp and the negative feedback.